# How to debug headless WiFi connection?

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, headless

I'm trying to run Raspberry Pi 3B+ in headless mode: I'm doing this by placing **ssh** and **wpa_supplicant.conf** files in the root of the boot SD card folder.

What I can do if something went wrong?

Is there any logs left on the SD cards **boot** folder to track back the problems if they are any using a Windows machine and a card reader?

Comment: Everything is logged in `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/messages`. Kernel messages (including messages from the WiFi driver) are logged in `/var/log/kern.log` or can be seen in real-time with a `dmesg` command. I run a script (from cron every three minutes) that pings 8.8.8.8 and restarts networking if the ping fails.

Comment: @Dougie, are these logs available from the SD card on a Windows machine?

Comment: No. You can read them on ANY Linux system. Windows doesn't understand EXT4 filesystems (due to not invented here).

Comment: You can boot a Linux Live CD (maybe from Debian or Ubuntu or any other). Raspberry Pi is about to get an entry into the linux world.

Comment: @Dougie, Windows does not understand. That's clear. But there is a *boot* folder which can be used to tell RPi about WiFi settings. So there is a way to have a feedback via exactly this folder.

Comment: It's not possible to move that to /boot there's too much logged. You can boot a Windows system with a Linux live CD. You can boot your Raspberry from another SDCard.